# Wierd compilation error on C++11 in-class member initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

I have a class that initializes a 'double' member variable something as below

```
class TESTY {
public:
  TESTY(){}
private:
  double m_double = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
};
```

And by creating instance as,

```
new TESTY();
```

I get the following error when compiling.

```
": internal error: IERROR_MODULE_ID_0
```

Not sure what's happening here and even google has no answer for this.
Am using intel64/icpc -gcc-version=430. Interestingly it works fine with C++14 [here](http://ideone.com/bsnr92)

Comment: Your code is correct. Internal error is always a bug in the compiler, and apparently you encountered one. BTW you do not need parens in the `new` statement - `new TESTY;` is enough and more common.

Comment: internal error == compiler bug. upgrade, re-test, report.

Comment: Its working [here](https://ideone.com/WZEASK)

Comment: Could you post exactly what command you are using to compile this, so that we know which flags you are using? Google says it might have to do something with the -ip flag.

Comment: @Johan: Thanks. I'll keep this post open so that if others bump into the same error they would know this is one of the possible causes

Comment: @Thomas : Even without any flags I get this error. Maybe this is an issue with the compiler version I am using

Comment: Isn't initializing values in the class definition a relatively new feature (e.g., C++11)?  Isn't gcc 4.3.0 relatively old?  Which library are you using?  Is numeric_limits<T>::max() marked as constexpr?